# Is it possible to use an externally defined function in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

In this example below I could call tester1(1,2) and get "z", '1' and '2' returned to the console.

```
var labelTreeSorterClosureTest1 = function() {
    var zVar = "z";
    return function(a,b) { console.log(zVar), console.log(a), console.log(b) }
}
var tester1 = labelTreeSorterClosureTest1();
```

But what if I wanted to use a function I had defined elsewhere, such as follows:

```
function externallyDefinedFunction(a,b) {
    console.log(zVar), console.log(a), console.log(b)
}
var labelTreeSorterClosureTest2 = function() {
    var zVar = "z";
    return externallyDefinedFunction;
}
var tester2 = labelTreeSorterClosureTest2();
```

If I call 'tester2(1,2)' I get an error saying that 'z' is undefined. Am I attempting to do something that has no meaning?

Comment: In the second example `externallyDefinedFunction` was declared not in the scope where `zVar` was defined. That's why you have an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how closures work. When a method is called, the context is switched to current method(unlike in c# or java) along with all the environment related to that function. So when it goes to invoke `externallyDefinedFunction`(which is externally defined) unlike the anonymous function that you return in first instance(which has access to zVar due to scope at which the function was defined)., there is no `zVar` defined.Make `zVar` a global variable or resolve the error or pass zVar reference or share zVar pass the instance `labelTreeSorterClosureTest2` inside `externallyDefinedFunction` using this.

**UPDATE**
can you do something like this ?

```
function externallyDefinedFunction(zVar, a,b) {
    console.log(zVar), console.log(a), console.log(b)
}


var labelTreeSorterClosureTest1 = function() {
    var zVar = "z";
    return function(a,b) { 
      externallyDefinedFunction(zVar, a, b); 
    }
}

var tester2 = labelTreeSorterClosureTest2();
tester2(1,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for this information Anand. My aim was to set the value of zVar in externallyDefinedFunction from outside the function. This would mean I could write externallyDefinedFunction once and have it called via a closure with different values of zVar. From what you're saying it sounds like this is not achievable?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know. But you can try some thing like this. See my update

Answer (score 0):

```
function externallyDefinedFunction(a,b) {
    // this variable is in the scope of the returned function
    var zVar = "in externallyDefinedFunction";
    console.log(zVar), console.log(a), console.log(b)
}
var labelTreeSorterClosureTest2 = function() {
    // this variable is private to the scope of labelTreeSorterClosureTest2
    var zVar = "i will never be seen!";
    return externallyDefinedFunction;
}
var tester2 = labelTreeSorterClosureTest2();
```

Comment: Thanks for this example papirtiger, but my aim is to set the value of zVar in externallyDefinedFunction from outside the function. This would mean I could write externallyDefinedFunction once and have it called via a closure with different values of zVar. It seems that this may not be possible though...